# Ratpack Servlet filter in java

Tags: filter, ratpack

I am looking for a single point of interception for Ratpack API based applications. Just like we have Web.xml in our regular Web based applications, does their exists anything in Ratpack API where I can handle or redirect requests to handlers in third party jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue myself by developing a  common handler and redirecting all incoming request to that handler. So no filters, every thing is handled by handlers in Ratpack.